# Swagger API documentation in Play application with Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, swagger

I'm developing a Play application in Scala as a hobby project. I'm using Gradle as a building tool.

I want to generate API documentation using swagger. My goal is to generate swagger.json file  containing my REST API documentation in JSON format with Gradle task during build of the project.

To generate the swagger file I'm using *swagger-gradle-plugin*. I have annotated controllers and methods in the controllers with proper annotations from *swagger.io.swagger_play* library.

Unfortunately, play annotations are not recognized by the plugin. File swagger.json generated using Gradle resolve task only picks up JAX-RS annotations I put in the controllers when trying to make plugin work.

For example, when I annotated a controller with

```
@Api(value="testController", tags = Array("Test controller")
```

annotation, the resolve task produced empty swagger.json file.

When I annotated the controller with JAX-RS annotation

```
@Path("/")
```

and then added JAX-RS annotations to the method inside the controller

```
@GET
@Path("testEndPoint1")
```

resolve task generated documentation for /testEndPoints1. But annotations from *swagger.io.swagger_play* are still ignored so there is not much information in the generated documentation.

I saw there are some plugins for sbt, but I want to make it work using Gradle.

Is there any way I can generate swagger REST API documentation in Play application while using Gradle building tool?

Versions of the tools in the project:

- Play 2.8
- Gradle 6.5.1
- Scala 2.12
- io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-gradle-plugin 2.1.6
- io.swagger:swagger.play_2.12:1.7.1

EDIT:

Gradle configuration of the plugin:

```
resolve {
outputFileName = "swagger"
outputDir = "build/swagger_doc"
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
readAllResources = true
openApiFile = file("openapi_config.yaml")
}
```